# How to bring a little arrow on the top of the dropdown in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, xcode6

[image: Ios drop down need little arrow]

I want to create a a drop down for my project, but i am unable to bring the arrow symbol as mentioned in the image

Please some one help me creating this dropdown.......

I want to create a a drop down for my project, but i am unable to bring the arrow symbol as mentioned in the image

Please some one help me creating this dropdown.......

```
@implementation DropdownViewController
@synthesize tabview;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Initialize table data
    menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"My Account", @"Terms of Use", @"Privacy Policy", @"Version",@"Logout", nil];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menu count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)btn1action:(id)sender
{
    if (self.tabview.hidden==YES)
    {
        self.tabview.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.tabview.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have idea triying  in tableview show and hide when click the round image but dont know to bring the image and not tried yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
UIImageView *arrowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"]];
arrowImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44); // Or whatever you like
arrowImageView.center = //circle button.center. The button where you want it to be displayed.
[self.view addSubview:arrowImageView];

// Set the table below the image and add it to subview
tableView.frame = // Your frame
```